# Redirect anonym user after click on link

Tags: 7, redirection

i have preprocess function

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    global $user;
    $view = $vars['view'];

    if ($view->name == 'questions_by_category' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
        $vars['header'] = '<div>' . l('Ask your question', 'node/add/question') . '</div>';
        if($user->uid == 0) {
            //this code not working
            if($_GET['q'] == 'node/add/question') {
                $path = drupal_get_path();
                drupal_goto('user/login', $path);
            }
        }
    }
```

i need to redirect anonym user to login page when he click on the link `node/add/question`, i also tried with `arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'question'` but this wont work.

The code inside `if($user->uid == 0) { }` works fine, i can redirect, but i need to redirect on click only. Also i need to redirect user back on the page after login, and this code :

```
$path = drupal_get_path();
drupal_goto('user/login', $path);
```

seems not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found solution, i just changed link for anonym user

```
if ($view->name == 'questions_by_category' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
        if ($user->uid) {
            $vars['header'] = '<div>' . l('Ask your question', 'node/add/question') . '</div>';
        }
        if ($user->uid == 0) {
            $vars['header'] = '<div>' . l('Ask your question', 'user/login') . '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: To redirect your users back to the page after login, you can use "?destination=page" parameter in url, like this: l('Ask your question', 'user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/add/question')))